# how to run a nodejs Script in php page

Tags: php, html, node.js, scada

im trying to build a html scada system using nodejs , php , html and css.

**my program** : i have this little 9 lines code in nodejs ; i use this code to communicat with a PLC in modbus rtu protocol. the code is working perfectly if i run it from terminal ;

**my problem** : im trying to run this code usinga php **submit button** inside html page, but i think that i missing something cuz its not working.

thank you .
**nodejs code** :

```
// create an empty modbus client
var ModbusRTU = require("modbus-serial");
var client = new ModbusRTU();
// open connection to a serial port
   client.connectRTUBuffered("COM2", { baudRate: 9600 ,parity: "even", dataBits: 8, stopBits: 1} , write );
     function write() {
    client.writeCoil(22, 1);
      
 }
```

**html code :** :

```
 <html>
<head>
<title>PHP isset() example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Sum" name="Submit1"><br/><br/>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Submit1"]))
{
  exec('write.js  >/dev/null/ 2>&1 &');  
}
?>
</form>
<script src="write.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't post images of code. Copy/paste all relevant code into the question itself. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to execute a js file which is not possible without an interpreter. Your `exec` code should look like this:

```
exec('node write.js')
```

Here `node` is the executable of you node instance.

Comment: thank you very much , its working but it works only one time. i mean i cannot execut the code twice or three times ...

Comment: @OussamaSalim Your HTML-form and PHP code seems fine. My guess is that your nodejs code has to do something with it. Can you execute it multiple times from the command line?

Comment: when i execute my code from terminal it works fine now when i execute the php code it run the jsfile only one time , after this i have to restart the laptop to be able to run the code onther time once .

Comment: is there anyway i can call a function from js file using php ?

Comment: @OussamaSalim No - this is not possible directly. You may use exec and node for that, but it will come with a huge performance overhead.